# Difference between FoxPro and Visual FoxPro

Tags: database, foxpro, visual-foxpro

What is the difference between `FoxPro` and `Visual FoxPro` ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_FoxPro

Comment: You could have [googled](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129976) it.

Comment: @Varad I didn't get the exact difference

Comment: @Y.E.P it is in the first paragraph of the Wikipedia article. "Visual FoxPro .... It is derived from FoxPro (originally known as FoxBASE)..."

Comment: +1. It's not always easy to grasp what Microsoft means when it adds "Visual" to the front of a product name, as it has done numerous times. I think it's perfectly reasonable to ask what it is that makes it "Visual".

Comment: It was visual because it included designers for forms and classes. There was actually a visual designer for forms in FoxPro 2.x, but the VFP version is more powerful and easier to use.

Answer (score 4):

Visual FoxPro is the successor to FoxPro. In the transition from FoxPro 2.6 to Visual FoxPro 3.0, many things were added including object orientation, a much improved tool for designed forms, built-in support for remote SQL databases and more. This article might help: http://www.tomorrowssolutionsllc.com/Articles/Learning%20Visual%20FoxPro%E2%80%94The%20Top%20Ten%20List.PDF

Answer (score 1):

'Visual' was just the Microsoft buzzword of the day - they were including the new Win32, OOP version of FoxPro in the Visual Studio suite of products and so they probably wanted to align the name with Visual BASIC, Visual InterDev and so on.